# Matching an Input Field against a Column of Wildcards

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Given the following table, where `wildcard` is a String:

```
ID   wildcard
1     foo
2     fo
3     f
```

I'd like to be able to build a Hibernate `Criterion` for matching against an input field that matches any of the `wildcard`'s fields.

The following example should clarify what I mean by "match":

querying with "foobar" should match all 3 of these rows since:

`foo%`, `fo%`, and `f%` all include foobar

In other words, I'd like the query to return where the input value begins with a row's `wildcard` column.

One way for me to do this would to be set an `or` criterion term where I check if the `wildcard` equals each of the pieces of `foobar`.

Example:

```
select * from table where wildcard = 'f' or wildcard = 'fo' or 
      wildcard = 'foo' or wildcard = 'foob' or 
          wildcard = 'fooba' or wildcard = 'foobar'
```

But I'm sure that I could do better?

How can I do this with a Hibernate `Criterion`?

Comment: Which database are you using? You may need database-specific code for this

Comment: I'd like to achieve this in Hibernate rather than a DB-specific code. Could you please say more as to a `code`? I'm not sure what you're discussing - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle/PostgresQL you can use:

```
select * from table where 'foobar' like wildcard || '%'
```

I'm not sure if the `||` string concatenation is Ansi SQL standard (I think not) so in other databases you need to replace it with the concatenation function or operator of that database.

Comment: thanks, Erwin, that query worked for me. I +1'd, but I'm still trying to figure out how to do this in Hibernate.

Comment: I'll put this as a comment since I'm not able to test it, but I think this should work: `Restrictions.sqlRestriction("'foobar' like {alias}.wildcard || '%'");`  (granted there should be nicer ways, but I'm not sure that the Criterion API can handle complex expressions like concatenation)